# R How to do weighted average calculations from two lists of matrices which relate to each other

Tags: r, list, matrix, weighted-average

I Have two lists of matrices. Both have the same "categories" as objects in the same order. These objects are always matrices.

```
**mylist_1**            
$region_1           
users   50  20  30
revenue 10000   3500    4000

$region_2           
users   20  20  60
revenue 5000    4000    10000



**mylist_2**            
$region_1           
% female    0.1 0.3 0.8
income  10000   25000   30000

$region_2           
% female    0.5 0.4 0.3
income  50000   20000   23000
```

I want to use the users from mylist_1 to calculate the weighted average of the metrics in list 2 (i.e. % female and average income). The users in list 1 for region_1 relate to the metrics for region_1 in list 2, the same applies relationship for region 2..So we want the weighted average from region 1 and 2 based on users, per column for each metric. i.e. to get the first number for income it would be

```
(50*10000+20*50000)/(50+20)
```

i.e. the output should look like:

output:

```
% female    0.21    0.35    0.47
income  21429   22500   25333
```

Comment: Can you explain where these values `(50*10000+20*50000)/(50+20)` come from? They don't seem to relate fully the the values you claim are in the two lists for `region_1`

Comment: so for the first column: 50 users in region 1 *income of 10000 in region 1 + 20 users in region 2 * income of 50000 in region 2. Divide all of this by the total of users in region 1 and 2 (50 and 20). treat each column seperately

Comment: OK, your words were misleading as you talk about region1 separately from region 2 (or at least it could be read that way)

Answer (score 0):

Following methods may be helpful:

```
mylist = list(
  list1=list(
    region_1 = list(
        users = c(20,50,100),
        revenue = c(10000, 25000, 15000)
        ),
    region_2 = list(
        users = c(25,40,85),
        revenue = c(15000, 15000, 5000)
        )
  ),
  list2= list(
    region_1 = list(
        pct_females = c(.2,.50,.100),
        income = c(10000, 25000, 15000)
        ),
    region_2 = list(
        pct_females = c(.25,.40,.85),
        income = c(15000, 15000, 5000)
        )
    )
)


mylist
$list1
$list1$region_1
$list1$region_1$users
[1]  20  50 100

$list1$region_1$revenue
[1] 10000 25000 15000


$list1$region_2
$list1$region_2$users
[1] 25 40 85

$list1$region_2$revenue
[1] 15000 15000  5000



$list2
$list2$region_1
$list2$region_1$pct_females
[1] 0.2 0.5 0.1

$list2$region_1$income
[1] 10000 25000 15000


$list2$region_2
$list2$region_2$pct_females
[1] 0.25 0.40 0.85

$list2$region_2$income
[1] 15000 15000  5000



ddf = data.frame(mylist)
ddf
  list1.region_1.users list1.region_1.revenue list1.region_2.users list1.region_2.revenue list2.region_1.pct_females
1                   20                  10000                   25                  15000                        0.2
2                   50                  25000                   40                  15000                        0.5
3                  100                  15000                   85                   5000                        0.1
  list2.region_1.income list2.region_2.pct_females list2.region_2.income
1                 10000                       0.25                 15000
2                 25000                       0.40                 15000
3                 15000                       0.85                  5000
>

# for income: 
(ddf[,"list1.region_1.users"] * ddf[,"list2.region_1.income"] +
    ddf[,"list1.region_2.users"] * ddf[,"list2.region_2.income"]) /
(ddf[,"list1.region_1.users"]+ ddf[,"list1.region_2.users"])
[1] 12777.78 20555.56 10405.41

# for percent females: 
(ddf[,"list1.region_1.users"] * ddf[,"list2.region_1.pct_females"] +
    ddf[,"list1.region_2.users"] * ddf[,"list2.region_2.pct_females"]) /
(ddf[,"list1.region_1.users"]+ ddf[,"list1.region_2.users"])
[1] 0.2277778 0.4555556 0.4445946
```

For a dataframe with same information:

```
ddf = structure(list(region = c("region_1", "region_1", "region_1", 
"region_2", "region_2", "region_2"), types = c("users", "percent_females", 
"income", "users", "percent_females", "income"), val1 = c(50, 
0.1, 10000, 20, 0.5, 50000), val2 = c(20, 0.3, 25000, 20, 0.4, 
20000), val3 = c(30, 0.8, 30000, 60, 0.3, 23000)), .Names = c("region", 
"types", "val1", "val2", "val3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ddf
    region           types  val1    val2    val3
1 region_1           users 5e+01    20.0    30.0
2 region_1 percent_females 1e-01     0.3     0.8
3 region_1          income 1e+04 25000.0 30000.0
4 region_2           users 2e+01    20.0    60.0
5 region_2 percent_females 5e-01     0.4     0.3
6 region_2          income 5e+04 20000.0 23000

 ddf$newcol = paste(ddf$region, ddf$types, sep="_")
> 
> ddf
    region           types  val1    val2    val3                   newcol
1 region_1           users 5e+01    20.0    30.0           region_1_users
2 region_1 percent_females 1e-01     0.3     0.8 region_1_percent_females
3 region_1          income 1e+04 25000.0 30000.0          region_1_income
4 region_2           users 2e+01    20.0    60.0           region_2_users
5 region_2 percent_females 5e-01     0.4     0.3 region_2_percent_females
6 region_2          income 5e+04 20000.0 23000.0          region_2_income
> 
# for income: 
col=3:5
> (ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_1_users',col]* ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_1_income',col]+
+         ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_2_users',col]* ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_2_income',col]) /
+         (ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_1_users',col]+ ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_2_users',col])
      val1  val2     val3
1 21428.57 22500 25333.33


# for percent females:
(ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_1_users',col]* ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_1_percent_females',col]+
 ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_2_users',col]* ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_2_percent_females',col]) /
 (ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_1_users',col]+ ddf[ddf$newcol=='region_2_users',col])
       val1 val2      val3
1 0.2142857 0.35 0.4666667
```